# How to recreate the same effect of highlighting with the reference attached?

Tags: javascript, arrays, highlight

I am working on a typing game and I am trying to imitate the same effect of highlighting of the characters to be typed like in https://www.ratatype.com/typing-test/test/. However, it was harder than what I imagined.

I created code which uses replace function to give style on the character. However, it only replaces the first instance of the character and the other instances, it won't do what it was supposed to do.

```
const originTextDiv =  document.getElementById('origin-text'); //the div that was supposed to be highlighted.

function spellCheck() {

let textEntered = textArea.value;
    //let textCharEntered = textEntered.split("");
    let originTextMatch = originText.substring(0, textEntered.length);
    // console.log(textEntered);
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    originChar = originText.split("");
    //console.log(originTextDiv);
    char = originTextDiv.textContent; 
    //console.log(char);

   console.log(originChar[index]);
     //console.log(textCharEntered);
    if (textEntered == originText) {
        textWrapper.style.borderColor = 'orange';

        $("#myModal").modal();
        stop();
    } else {
        if (textEntered == originTextMatch) {
            textWrapper.style.borderColor = 'green';
            textArea.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            //  if (!(key == 20 || key == 16 || key == 18 || key == 8 || key == 46 || key ==17 )){
                originTextDiv.innerHTML = char.replace(originChar[index], '<span style="background-color:green;">' +originChar[index]+ '</span>'); //here is the code where it is highlighting
                ++index;
            //  }
            // if (key == 8 || key == 46){
            //     --index;
            // }
        } else {
            textWrapper.style.borderColor = 'red';
            textArea.style.backgroundColor='f23a49';
            originTextDiv.innerHTML = char.replace(originChar[index], '<span style="background-color:red;">' +originChar[index]+ '</span>');
            if (!(key == 8 || key == 46)){
                error++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I expected to have it work as intended but I didn't knew replace only replaces the first instance. I tried to look at on replaceAt functions for javascript but when I tried it the replaceAt also replaces the span tag attached. Could someone give me some pointers on how to recreate the same effect as the reference above?